# How to Display Number of Sessions in Day, Afternoon and Evening in Datadog Dashboard

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I am looking to create a dashboard in datadog with a user list that are using the app in the morning between 09:00 am to 12:00 pm, and between 12:00 to 03:00 pm and between 04:00 to 06:00 pm. I am not finding the timeseries widget so useful for the above requirement.
Appreciate if someone can help me in this regard.